# Filter nested array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter my events object using an id. If one of the events has a category ID matching, then I want to add it to a new object.

I am updating my original question, as the `dots` property is an array of objects. So the answers below will not work

I have a basic [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mharrisweb/6tnjvf62/4/)

```
    const selectedId = 62;
    const filteredEvents = {};
    const events = {
  "2018-01-31": {
    dots: [{
      key: "test",
      color: "red",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }, {
        name: "cat 2",
        id: 61
      }, {
        name: "cat 3",
        id: 62
      }]
    }]
  },
  "2018-02-02": {
    dots: [{
      key: "test 1",
      color: "blue",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }]
    }]
  },
  "2018-02-04": {
    dots: [{
      key: "test 2",
      color: "pink",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }]
    }, {
      key: "test 2",
      color: "pink",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }]
    }]
  }
};
```

Trying to filter here:

```
Object.keys(events).dots.categories.filter(category => {
    category.id === selectedId // remove if matching
});
```

I would only want this property in the filtered object as it has a category id of 62:

```
const events = {
  "2018-01-31": {
    dots: [{
      key: "test",
      color: "red",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }, {
        name: "cat 2",
        id: 61
      }, {
        name: "cat 3",
        id: 62
      }]
    }]
  }
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I have provided code and a fiddle.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well

Comment: Not sure why. Could you also please add what you'd like the result to look like? It's not clear whether you want an array of events, or an array of categories

Comment: The downvote is probably because your actual question doesn't seem to exist. What exactly is it you're asking? What should inputs/outputs look like?

Comment: Try opening the console and [debugging](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp). You clearly have errors.

Comment: Numerous problems with that filter. Start by looking at what `Object.keys(events)` produces.  Also please show what expected results are

Comment: Do you want a new object entirely or do you want to delete filtered items from the original object?

Comment: Object.keys(events) will return you an array with the key names so you cannot access the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.values()` to convert an object to an array of values, `.find()` to get the object having `id` equal to `selectedId`

```
const results = Object.values(events).filter(({dots:{categories}}) => 
    categories.find(({id}) => id === selectedId)
).pop();
```

Comment: `dots` is actually an array of objects (events). How can the above example work with the array of objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to build the new object.

```
// Get the key for each event
let result = Object.keys(events).reduce((result, key) => {
    // Check if the categories contain a matching ID
    if (events[key].dots.categories.some(cat => cat.id === selectedId)) {
        // Add it to the results
        result[key] = events[key];
    }
    return result;
}, {});
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
const selectedId = 62;
const filteredEvents = {};
const events = {
  "2018-01-31": {
    dots: {
      key: "test",
      color: "red",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }, {
        name: "cat 2",
        id: 61
      }, {
        name: "cat 3",
        id: 62
      }]
    }
  },
  "2018-02-02": {
    dots: {
      key: "test 1",
      color: "blue",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }]
    }
  },
  "2018-02-04": {
    dots: {
      key: "test 2",
      color: "pink",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }]
    }
  }
};


let result = Object.keys(events).reduce((result, key) => {
    if (events[key].dots.categories.some(cat => cat.id === selectedId)) {
      result[key] = events[key];
    }
    return result;
}, {});


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the keys of the object by checking if the inner array has the wanted `id`.

Then build a new object with the given keys.

```js
var selectedId = 62,
    filteredEvents = {},
    events = { "2018-01-31": { dots: { key: "test", color: "red", categories: [{ name: "cat 1", id: 59 }, { name: "cat 2", id: 61 }, { name: "cat 3", id: 62 }] } }, "2018-02-02": { dots: { key: "test 1", color: "blue", categories: [{ name: "cat 1", id: 59 }] } }, "2018-02-04": { dots: { key: "test 2", color: "pink", categories: [{ name: "cat 1", id: 59 }] } } };

Object.assign(filteredEvents, ...Object
    .keys(events)
    .filter(k => events[k].dots.categories.some(({ id }) => id === selectedId))
    .map(k => ({ [k]: events[k] }))
);

console.log(filteredEvents);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const selectedId = 62;
const filteredEvents = {};
const events = {
  "2018-01-31": {
    dots: {
      key: "test",
      color: "red",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }, {
        name: "cat 2",
        id: 61
      }, {
        name: "cat 3",
        id: 62
      }]
    }
  },
  "2018-02-02": {
    dots: {
      key: "test 1",
      color: "blue",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }]
    }
  },
  "2018-02-04": {
    dots: {
      key: "test 2",
      color: "pink",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }]
    }
  }
};
Object.keys(events).forEach(function(element) {
   // console.log(events[element].dots.categories);
    events[element].dots.categories.forEach(function(category) {
      if (category.id === selectedId) {
        filteredEvents[element] = events[element];
      }
  });
});
console.log(filteredEvents);
```