# filter array using nested value gives me undefined

Tags: javascript

How can I filter a top level array using a value from a nested array?

I have my code below, and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mharrisweb/6tnjvf62/7/)

```
const selectedId = 62;
const filteredEvents = {};
const events = {
  "2018-01-31": {
    dots: [{
      key: "test",
      color: "red",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }, {
        name: "cat 2",
        id: 61
      }, {
        name: "cat 3",
        id: 62
      }]
    }, {
      key: "test again",
      color: "blue",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }, {
        name: "cat 2",
        id: 61
      }]
    }]
  },
  "2018-02-02": {
    dots: [{
      key: "test 1",
      color: "blue",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }]
    }]
  },
  "2018-02-04": {
    dots: [{
      key: "test 2",
      color: "pink",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }]
    }, {
      key: "test 2",
      color: "pink",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }]
    }]
  }
};
```

Using this filter:

```
   const results = Object.values(events)
                .filter(({ dots: [event] }) => {
                    event.categories.find(
                        category => category.id === selectedId
                    );
                })
                .pop();

// console.log(results) undefined
```

I would only want this property in the filtered object as it has a category id of 62:

```
const events = {
  "2018-01-31": {
    dots: [{
      key: "test",
      color: "red",
      categories: [{
        name: "cat 1",
        id: 59
      }, {
        name: "cat 2",
        id: 61
      }, {
        name: "cat 3",
        id: 62
      }]
    }]
  }
```

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241687/filter-nested-array

Comment: Your `.filter()` callback has no `return` statement. Either remove the braces enclosing the callback's body, or add `return` before the returned expression;

Comment: Data is different from my previous question, `dots` is an object in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a slight oversight in that filter. It's an arrow function, and it needs to explicitly return in this form:

```
filter(({ dots: [event] }) => {
    // add "return" here
    return event.categories.find(category => category.id === selectedId);
})
```

Since you're not doing anything else in that block, you can omit the parentheses and return:

```
filter(({ dots: [event] }) => event.categories.find(category => category.id === selectedId))
```

Otherwise, your filter function always returns undefined, which means filter takes everything out, so your pop() comes up with nothing.

Comment: It is parameters destructuring. That `.filter()` takes a function as argument. That function gets parameters as well. We destructure it right there in the function params.

Comment: Yes, but then you're only ever checking the first object in the `dots` array.

Comment: Yep. But that is out of the scope of the answer, I've only pointed out that the OP is NOT returning anything from that map function. I guess they'll find out later if they need more.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in my comment, you're not returning anything from the filter callback.

Also, your destructuring assignment is explicitly capturing the first object in the `dots` array instead of all of them. Since looking at your previous question, you want to search all categories, you'll need to reference the entire array to get all categories of all objects in `dots`.

```js
const events = {"2018-01-31":{"dots":[{"key":"test","color":"red","categories":[{"name":"cat 1","id":59},{"name":"cat 2","id":61},{"name":"cat 3","id":62}]},{"key":"test again","color":"blue","categories":[{"name":"cat 1","id":59},{"name":"cat 2","id":61}]}]},"2018-02-02":{"dots":[{"key":"test 1","color":"blue","categories":[{"name":"cat 1","id":59}]}]},"2018-02-04":{"dots":[{"key":"test 2","color":"pink","categories":[{"name":"cat 1","id":59}]},{"key":"test 2","color":"pink","categories":[{"name":"cat 1","id":59}]}]}};

const target = 62;

const results = Object.entries(events)
  .filter(([_, o]) => o.dots.some(oo => oo.categories.some(c => c.id === target)))
  .reduce((res, [k,o]) => ({...res, [k]:o}), {});

console.log(results);
```

I removed the `.pop()` at the end, since that would give you the *last* match if multiple are found. Not sure why that's there. If you want all matches, then it definitely shouldn't be there. If you only want one, I'd use `.find()` instead of `.filter()`. If you want the last match, I'd still use `.find()` but would first `.reverse()` the array of values.

I also used `.some()` instead of `.find()` on the nested arrays, since that gives a more appropriate boolean result instead of grabbing a nested object that isn't actually needed. It doesn't make a difference here, but I think it's better form.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I keep the parent date, so the results are `{
  "2018-01-31": {dots:[etc...]` rather than just show the dots array.

Comment: @Bomber: I wondered if maybe you'd want that. I updated the answer. It uses `.entries()` to keep the keys with the values and uses `.reduce()` to convert the keys/values back to an object.